# Best way to Search google plus business pages in a locality in google

Tags: google-maps, google-search, google-search-api

I need to search for "painters in london" and I am looking for having a result of google plus business pages pages listing.

I know that I can search Google maps, Maps really screws up on slow internet connection.

Is there an easy way to do this, like search query parameters or a custom search.

I did find a similar service here www.gpluspagesearch.com/ here but prefer to use the normal clean google.

I am open to any suggestion starting from normal search query tweaking to any custom Google Api's.

Comment: Have you checked [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)?

Comment: Definately leave out the word "in" in your search. There's nothing one will find, based on that word. Remove similar words as well (the, for, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try google places API, i've used it for a project, it is good you can search places by a city, county or geo location, you can also store new places that are not in google database. it is simple to use and free.

to find it go to: https://console.developers.google.com/ -> APIs & auth -> APIs -> Places API

here is the documentation link: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

and this is a good video tutorial from google I/O on how to use it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCgTAWXwjOk

Comment: Your answer shed a lot of light to my research. Although not a complete solution, I can start pitching with API first. Thanks Much, awarding you the bounty here with.